# Redirecting links hiding the link name

Tags: php, html

I have 2 links.

For example - When a person clicks on the button "click here" - it should show www.google.com on the link bar, but it should redirect to "www.yahoo.com" and the person should not be able to see this "www.yahoo.com".

Yahoo and google are just used as an example.

How can I do that?

Comment: You can only achieve this by using a big frame on the original page. This is not user friendly and the remote page can block you from doing so pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

This was so ridiculously easy I guess this cannot be a hackers big secret.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" style="text-decoration:underline" onclick="location.href='http://yahoo.com';return false;">Click HERE to be lured into my fake banking site</a>
```

Although it does require javascript to be active on the browser

Comment: What would the javascript be?

Answer (score 0):

I would "recommend" using a full page iframe like this:

Upload a file to your server that contains this (in your example your server would be Yahoo!)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    body, html, iframe {margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; border: none}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe src="https://google.com">
</body>
</html>
```

This should work alright for you and give the effect that the link is actually located on your own domain. Causing the APK download to look like it's on your machine.

The source domain can break free from the iFrame and therefore break your illusion. Many sites will do that, but it will still work properly for most of your needs.